# Java8 DateTimeFormatter am/pm

Tags: java, java-8, java-time

I am trying to parse some dates, but the DateTimeParser seems to disagree with me on what is valid

```
import java.time.ZonedDateTime
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter
import java.util.Locale

ZonedDateTime.parse("Wed Jul 16, 2016 4:38pm EDT", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE MMM dd, yyyy hh:mma z", Locale.US))
```

When I try this it says

```
java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text 'Wed Jul 16, 2016 4:38pm EDT' could not be parsed at index 17
```

So something is wrong with the hours? When I drop one of the 'h' it gets further ( altough it should just 0-pad my hours ), but then it doesn't like the pm-stuff

```
ZonedDateTime.parse("Wed Jul 16, 2016 4:38pm EDT", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE MMM dd, yyyy h:mma z", Locale.US))
java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text 'Wed Jul 16, 2016 4:38pm EDT' could not be parsed at index 21
```

I don't know what his exact problem is. When I try 'hh:mmaa' as a pattern it says that it doesn't like two a and now i am stuck, since the error messages are not helpful.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`a` expects either `PM` or `AM` in upper case. To get a case insensitive formatter you need to build it manually:

```
DateTimeFormatter fmt = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
        .parseCaseInsensitive()
        .appendPattern("EEE MMM dd, yyyy h:mma z")
        .toFormatter(Locale.US);
```

Note that you will get a new error because the 16th of July is not a Wednesday.

Comment: wow.. Any idea why the default doesn't support lower case? I was converting old java.util.Date code to java.time and the SimpleDateFormat had no problems with it.

Comment: The case depends upon your locale setting. See my answer below.

Answer (score 7):

Note that the case of `AM` and `PM` depends on your locale!

So if your locale is US it's expected to be upper case, but if it's UK it's expected to be lower case.

See: [Localize the period (AM/PM) in a time stamp to another language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54511231/localize-the-period-am-pm-in-a-time-stamp-to-another-language) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out this solution also resolves trying to parse mixed-case months (e.g., "Jul") using "MMM".