# Localize the period (AM/PM) in a time stamp to another language

Tags: java, android, kotlin, localization, internationalization

I would like to have the period in a timestamp to use different notation than am/pm. Can this translation be done?

current format : dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm aa
eg . 01/02/2019 05:37 PM

required: 
    01/02/2019 05:37 chiều

Notice the "chiều" instead of PM. This is required.

Comment: Why the down-vote? This is a valid useful Question.

Comment: The question wasn't clear previously and someone thought it was a duplicate.

Comment: @BasilBourque Version 1 of this question wasn't very good

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## tl;dr

Specify a `Locale`.

```
DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "hh:mm a" , locale )  // Pass a `Locale` to specify human language and cultural norms for localization.
```

## Yes, you can localize AM/PM

The modern approach uses the *java.time* classes that years ago supplanted the terrible legacy classes (`Date`, `Calendar`, `SimpleDateFormat`).

The `Locale` specified on the `DateTimeFormatter` determines the human language and cultural norms used in localization.

```
LocalTime lt = LocalTime.of( 17 , 0 );
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "hh:mm a" );
for ( Locale locale : Locale.getAvailableLocales() ) {
    String output = lt.format( f.withLocale( locale ) );
    System.out.println( locale.getDisplayName( Locale.US ) + " ➙ " + output );
}
```

Output, Java 11, [using an OpenJDK-based JVM](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/55078/1255).

```
Norwegian Nynorsk ➙ 05:00 ettermiddag
Arabic (Jordan) ➙ 05:00 م
Bulgarian ➙ 05:00 сл.об.
Kabuverdianu ➙ 05:00 pm
Low German ➙ 05:00 PM
Zulu ➙ 05:00 PM
Amharic (Ethiopia) ➙ 05:00 ከሰዓት
French (Algeria) ➙ 05:00 PM
Tigrinya (Ethiopia) ➙ 05:00 ድሕር ሰዓት
Tibetan (China) ➙ 05:00 ཕྱི་དྲོ་
Upper Sorbian ➙ 05:00 popołdnju
Quechua (Ecuador) ➙ 05:00 p.m.
Tamil (Singapore) ➙ 05:00 பிற்பகல்
Latvian ➙ 05:00 pēcpusdienā
English (Niue) ➙ 05:00 PM
Chinese (Simplified, Singapore) ➙ 05:00 下午
English (Montserrat) ➙ 05:00 PM
English (Guernsey) ➙ 05:00 PM
English (Jamaica) ➙ 05:00 PM
Volapük ➙ 05:00 PM
Kako ➙ 05:00 PM
Serbian (Montenegro) ➙ 05:00 po podne
Swedish (Sweden) ➙ 05:00 em
Spanish (Bolivia) ➙ 05:00 p. m.
Dzongkha (Bhutan) ➙ 05:00 ཕྱི་ཆ་
Meru ➙ 05:00 ŨG
Sakha ➙ 05:00 ЭК
English (Zambia) ➙ 05:00 PM
French (Mali) ➙ 05:00 PM
Breton ➙ 05:00 G.M.
Hausa (Nigeria) ➙ 05:00 PM
Arabic (Saudi Arabia) ➙ 05:00 م
Persian (Afghanistan) ➙ 05:00 بعدازظهر
Lower Sorbian (Germany) ➙ 05:00 wótpołdnja
Slovak ➙ 05:00 PM
Ossetic (Georgia) ➙ 05:00 ӕмбисбоны фӕстӕ
Malayalam ➙ 05:00 PM
English (Malta) ➙ 05:00 PM
English (Liberia) ➙ 05:00 PM
Arabic (Chad) ➙ 05:00 م
English (Ghana) ➙ 05:00 PM
English (Israel) ➙ 05:00 PM
Swedish ➙ 05:00 em
Czech ➙ 05:00 odp.
Greek ➙ 05:00 μ.μ.
Central Atlas Tamazight (Morocco) ➙ 05:00 Ḍeffir aza
Afrikaans ➙ 05:00 nm.
Swahili (Uganda) ➙ 05:00 PM
Koyraboro Senni (Mali) ➙ 05:00 Aluula
Inari Sami ➙ 05:00 ep.
Turkmen (Turkmenistan) ➙ 05:00 günortadan soň
Serbian (Cyrillic, Montenegro) ➙ 05:00 по подне
Arabic (Egypt) ➙ 05:00 م
Lower Sorbian ➙ 05:00 wótpołdnja
Lakota (United States) ➙ 05:00 PM
Vai (Latin, Liberia) ➙ 05:00 PM
Yiddish (World) ➙ 05:00 נאָכמיטאָג
Yoruba (Nigeria) ➙ 05:00 Ọ̀sán
Northern Sami (Norway) ➙ 05:00 eahketbeaivet
Koyra Chiini ➙ 05:00 Aluula
Swahili (Congo - Kinshasa) ➙ 05:00 PM
Volapük (World) ➙ 05:00 PM
English (Palau) ➙ 05:00 PM
Polish (Poland) ➙ 05:00 PM
Filipino (Philippines) ➙ 05:00 PM
Italian (Vatican City) ➙ 05:00 PM
Serbian (Serbia and Montenegro) ➙ 05:00 PM
Nepali (India) ➙ 05:00 अपराह्न
Spanish (Philippines) ➙ 05:00 p. m.
Spanish (Spain) ➙ 05:00 p. m.
Spanish (Colombia) ➙ 05:00 p. m.
Bulgarian (Bulgaria) ➙ 05:00 сл.об.
Yiddish ➙ 05:00 נאָכמיטאָג
Arabic (Western Sahara) ➙ 05:00 م
Bosnian (Latin, Bosnia & Herzegovina) ➙ 05:00 popodne
English (St. Vincent & Grenadines) ➙ 05:00 PM
Low German (Germany) ➙ 05:00 PM
Norwegian Bokmål (Svalbard & Jan Mayen) ➙ 05:00 p.m.
Spanish (United States) ➙ 05:00 p. m.
Aghem ➙ 05:00 a.k
Upper Sorbian (Germany) ➙ 05:00 popołdnju
English (United States, Computer) ➙ 05:00 PM
English (Europe) ➙ 05:00 PM
Arabic (Sudan) ➙ 05:00 م
English (St. Kitts & Nevis) ➙ 05:00 PM
Hausa (Niger) ➙ 05:00 PM
Portuguese (Macau SAR China) ➙ 05:00 da tarde
Embu ➙ 05:00 UT
Romanian (Romania) ➙ 05:00 p.m.
Chinese (Simplified) ➙ 05:00 下午
Luxembourgish (Luxembourg) ➙ 05:00 nomëttes
Serbian (Latin, Montenegro) ➙ 05:00 po podne
Spanish (Guatemala) ➙ 05:00 p. m.
Somali (Kenya) ➙ 05:00 gn.
Zarma (Niger) ➙ 05:00 Zaarikay b
Basaa (Cameroon) ➙ 05:00 I ɓugajɔp
French (St. Pierre & Miquelon) ➙ 05:00 PM
Arabic (Comoros) ➙ 05:00 م
French (Madagascar) ➙ 05:00 PM
Norwegian (Norway, Nynorsk) ➙ 05:00 ettermiddag
Spanish (Chile) ➙ 05:00 p. m.
Mongolian ➙ 05:00 ү.х
Aghem (Cameroon) ➙ 05:00 a.k
Kamba (Kenya) ➙ 05:00 Ĩyawĩoo
Teso ➙ 05:00 Ebongi
Turkish (Turkey) ➙ 05:00 ÖS
Basque ➙ 05:00 PM
Persian (Iran) ➙ 05:00 بعدازظهر
English (Macau SAR China) ➙ 05:00 PM
Wolof ➙ 05:00 Ngo
Tachelhit (Tifinagh) ➙ 05:00 ⵜⴰⴷⴳⴳⵯⴰⵜ
English (Belize) ➙ 05:00 PM
Albanian (Albania) ➙ 05:00 e pasdites
Arabic (Mauritania) ➙ 05:00 م
Spanish (Dominican Republic) ➙ 05:00 p. m.
Russian ➙ 05:00 PM
Tasawaq (Niger) ➙ 05:00 Zaarikay b
Azerbaijani ➙ 05:00 PM
Kwasio (Cameroon) ➙ 05:00 kugú
Persian ➙ 05:00 بعدازظهر
Kalaallisut (Greenland) ➙ 05:00 PM
English (Nauru) ➙ 05:00 PM
North Ndebele ➙ 05:00 PM
Kazakh ➙ 05:00 PM
Azerbaijani (Cyrillic) ➙ 05:00 ПМ
English (Northern Mariana Islands) ➙ 05:00 PM
English (Grenada) ➙ 05:00 PM
Turkmen ➙ 05:00 günortadan soň
Armenian ➙ 05:00 ԿՀ
Tachelhit (Latin) ➙ 05:00 tadggʷat
English (Botswana) ➙ 05:00 PM
English (Australia) ➙ 05:00 pm
English (Cyprus) ➙ 05:00 PM
Kabyle (Algeria) ➙ 05:00 n tmeddit
Makonde (Tanzania) ➙ 05:00 Chilo
Tamil (Malaysia) ➙ 05:00 பிற்பகல்
Tigrinya (Eritrea) ➙ 05:00 ድሕር ሰዓት
Nuer (South Sudan) ➙ 05:00 TŊ
English (Rwanda) ➙ 05:00 PM
North Ndebele (Zimbabwe) ➙ 05:00 PM
Swedish (Finland) ➙ 05:00 em
Shambala ➙ 05:00 nyiaghuo
Luo ➙ 05:00 OT
Luxembourgish ➙ 05:00 nomëttes
Nepali ➙ 05:00 अपराह्न
English (Ireland) ➙ 05:00 p.m.
Chinese (Singapore) ➙ 05:00 下午
Lingala (Congo - Kinshasa) ➙ 05:00 mpókwa
English (Kiribati) ➙ 05:00 PM
Ngiemboon (Cameroon) ➙ 05:00 ncwònzém
Oromo (Ethiopia) ➙ 05:00 WB
Norwegian ➙ 05:00 p.m.
Japanese (Japan) ➙ 05:00 午後
Burmese ➙ 05:00 ညနေ
Georgian ➙ 05:00 PM
Arabic (Israel) ➙ 05:00 م
Makhuwa-Meetto ➙ 05:00 mchochil’l
Odia (India) ➙ 05:00 PM
French (St. Martin) ➙ 05:00 PM
Tachelhit ➙ 05:00 ⵜⴰⴷⴳⴳⵯⴰⵜ
Kalaallisut ➙ 05:00 PM
English (Swaziland) ➙ 05:00 PM
Rwa (Tanzania) ➙ 05:00 kyiukonyi
Chinese ➙ 05:00 下午
Spanish (Peru) ➙ 05:00 p. m.
Makhuwa-Meetto (Mozambique) ➙ 05:00 mchochil’l
Samburu ➙ 05:00 Teipa
Azerbaijani (Latin) ➙ 05:00 PM
Tamil ➙ 05:00 பிற்பகல்
English (United Kingdom) ➙ 05:00 pm
Langi ➙ 05:00 MUU
Chinese (Traditional, Hong Kong SAR China) ➙ 05:00 下午
Arabic (Syria) ➙ 05:00 م
Bafia (Cameroon) ➙ 05:00 cɛɛ́nko
Tibetan ➙ 05:00 ཕྱི་དྲོ་
Kazakh (Kazakhstan) ➙ 05:00 PM
Spanish (Panama) ➙ 05:00 p. m.
Tatar (Russia) ➙ 05:00 PM
Oromo (Kenya) ➙ 05:00 WB
Arabic (Palestinian Territories) ➙ 05:00 م
English (American Samoa) ➙ 05:00 PM
French (Vanuatu) ➙ 05:00 PM
Chinese (Taiwan) ➙ 05:00 下午
Bena ➙ 05:00 pamunyi
Kalenjin ➙ 05:00 kooskoliny
French (Monaco) ➙ 05:00 PM
Cornish ➙ 05:00 p.m.
Portuguese (Mozambique) ➙ 05:00 da tarde
French (Niger) ➙ 05:00 PM
Vai (Latin) ➙ 05:00 PM
Shambala (Tanzania) ➙ 05:00 nyiaghuo
Colognian ➙ 05:00 Uhr nommendaachs
Urdu (India) ➙ 05:00 PM
Lingala ➙ 05:00 mpókwa
English (Jersey) ➙ 05:00 PM
Swiss German (Switzerland) ➙ 05:00 am Namittag
Lingala (Central African Republic) ➙ 05:00 mpókwa
English (Christmas Island) ➙ 05:00 PM
Luyia (Kenya) ➙ 05:00 p.m.
Portuguese ➙ 05:00 PM
English (Austria) ➙ 05:00 PM
Galician ➙ 05:00 p.m.
Kako (Cameroon) ➙ 05:00 PM
Serbian (Cyrillic) ➙ 05:00 по подне
Cantonese (Simplified, China) ➙ 05:00 下午
Spanish (Equatorial Guinea) ➙ 05:00 p. m.
Kannada (India) ➙ 05:00 ಅಪರಾಹ್ನ
Arabic (Yemen) ➙ 05:00 م
Tongan ➙ 05:00 efiafi
English (Sint Maarten) ➙ 05:00 PM
Irish ➙ 05:00 i.n.
Quechua ➙ 05:00 p.m.
Russian (Kazakhstan) ➙ 05:00 PM
English (Tanzania) ➙ 05:00 PM
Estonian ➙ 05:00 PM
English (Puerto Rico) ➙ 05:00 PM
Mundang ➙ 05:00 lilli
Korean (North Korea) ➙ 05:00 오후
Indonesian ➙ 05:00 PM
Pashto ➙ 05:00 غ.و.
Shona ➙ 05:00 PM
Dutch (Suriname) ➙ 05:00 p.m.
Rombo ➙ 05:00 kingoto
English (Bahamas) ➙ 05:00 PM
Khmer ➙ 05:00 PM
Standard Moroccan Tamazight ➙ 05:00 ⵜⴰⴷⴳⴳⵯⴰⵜ
French (New Caledonia) ➙ 05:00 PM
Belarusian ➙ 05:00 PM
Manx ➙ 05:00 p.m.
Spanish ➙ 05:00 p. m.
Duala ➙ 05:00 ebyámu
Scottish Gaelic (United Kingdom) ➙ 05:00 f
Ngomba ➙ 05:00 ŋka mbɔ́t nji
Dutch (Caribbean Netherlands) ➙ 05:00 p.m.
French (Cameroon) ➙ 05:00 soir
Swiss German ➙ 05:00 am Namittag
Uzbek (Cyrillic, Uzbekistan) ➙ 05:00 ТК
Punjabi (Gurmukhi, India) ➙ 05:00 ਬਾ.ਦੁ.
English (Kenya) ➙ 05:00 PM
Gusii ➙ 05:00 Mog
Morisyen ➙ 05:00 PM
Asu (Tanzania) ➙ 05:00 ichamthi
Teso (Uganda) ➙ 05:00 Ebongi
Japanese ➙ 05:00 午後
French (Senegal) ➙ 05:00 PM
Odia ➙ 05:00 PM
Bodo ➙ 05:00 बेलासे
French (Morocco) ➙ 05:00 p.m.
Portuguese (Luxembourg) ➙ 05:00 da tarde
French (St. Barthélemy) ➙ 05:00 PM
English (Netherlands) ➙ 05:00 PM
Metaʼ (Cameroon) ➙ 05:00 PM
Lingala (Congo - Brazzaville) ➙ 05:00 mpókwa
Telugu ➙ 05:00 PM
Slovenian ➙ 05:00 pop.
Korean (South Korea) ➙ 05:00 오후
Greek (Cyprus) ➙ 05:00 μ.μ.
Marathi (India) ➙ 05:00 म.उ.
Hausa ➙ 05:00 PM
Spanish (Mexico) ➙ 05:00 p. m.
Northern Luri (Iran) ➙ 05:00 PM
Swiss German (France) ➙ 05:00 am Namittag
Spanish (Honduras) ➙ 05:00 p. m.
Hungarian (Hungary) ➙ 05:00 du.
Fulah (Senegal) ➙ 05:00 kikiiɗe
Sangu ➙ 05:00 Pashamihe
Albanian (Macedonia) ➙ 05:00 e pasdites
Serbian (Cyrillic, Bosnia & Herzegovina) ➙ 05:00 по подне
Finnish ➙ 05:00 ip.
Uzbek ➙ 05:00 TK
Bosnian (Cyrillic) ➙ 05:00 поподне
Estonian (Estonia) ➙ 05:00 PM
Serbian (Latin) ➙ 05:00 po podne
English (South Sudan) ➙ 05:00 PM
Swahili ➙ 05:00 PM
Tibetan (India) ➙ 05:00 ཕྱི་དྲོ་
Western Frisian (Netherlands) ➙ 05:00 PM
Arabic (Oman) ➙ 05:00 م
Turkish (Cyprus) ➙ 05:00 ÖS
Kwasio ➙ 05:00 kugú
Romansh ➙ 05:00 PM
English (Madagascar) ➙ 05:00 PM
French (Burundi) ➙ 05:00 PM
Uzbek (Latin, Uzbekistan) ➙ 05:00 TK
Bangla ➙ 05:00 PM
Duala (Cameroon) ➙ 05:00 ebyámu
German (Italy) ➙ 05:00 nachm.
Northern Luri (Iraq) ➙ 05:00 PM
Vai (Vai) ➙ 05:00 PM
Kannada ➙ 05:00 ಅಪರಾಹ್ನ
French (Tunisia) ➙ 05:00 PM
Serbian (Serbia) ➙ 05:00 по подне
German (Switzerland) ➙ 05:00 nachm.
Bangla (Bangladesh) ➙ 05:00 PM
Ngiemboon ➙ 05:00 ncwònzém
French (French Polynesia) ➙ 05:00 PM
English (South Africa) ➙ 05:00 PM
Gujarati ➙ 05:00 PM
Portuguese (Equatorial Guinea) ➙ 05:00 da tarde
Vunjo (Tanzania) ➙ 05:00 kyiukonyi
Machame (Tanzania) ➙ 05:00 kyiukonyi
English (Tuvalu) ➙ 05:00 PM
Lao ➙ 05:00 ຫຼັງທ່ຽງ
French (France) ➙ 05:00 PM
English (Pitcairn Islands) ➙ 05:00 PM
English (Marshall Islands) ➙ 05:00 PM
French (Benin) ➙ 05:00 PM
Chinese (Traditional) ➙ 05:00 下午
Church Slavic (Russia) ➙ 05:00 PM
Chinese (Simplified, Hong Kong SAR China) ➙ 05:00 下午
Dutch (Netherlands) ➙ 05:00 p.m.
Sakha (Russia) ➙ 05:00 ЭК
English (Guyana) ➙ 05:00 PM
Pashto (Afghanistan) ➙ 05:00 غ.و.
Bosnian (Latin) ➙ 05:00 popodne
Kyrgyz ➙ 05:00 түштөн кийинки
Masai ➙ 05:00 Ɛndámâ
Jola-Fonyi (Senegal) ➙ 05:00 PM
Ossetic ➙ 05:00 ӕмбисбоны фӕстӕ
Bosnian (Cyrillic, Bosnia & Herzegovina) ➙ 05:00 поподне
Dutch (Curaçao) ➙ 05:00 p.m.
Arabic (Algeria) ➙ 05:00 م
Slovak (Slovakia) ➙ 05:00 PM
Portuguese (Switzerland) ➙ 05:00 da tarde
French (Equatorial Guinea) ➙ 05:00 PM
Fulah (Cameroon) ➙ 05:00 kikiiɗe
Amharic ➙ 05:00 ከሰዓት
English (Nigeria) ➙ 05:00 PM
French (Côte d’Ivoire) ➙ 05:00 PM
Kikuyu (Kenya) ➙ 05:00 Hwaĩ-inĩ
English (Pakistan) ➙ 05:00 PM
Chinese (China) ➙ 05:00 下午
English (St. Lucia) ➙ 05:00 PM
Kinyarwanda ➙ 05:00 PM
Bodo (India) ➙ 05:00 बेलासे
Wolof (Senegal) ➙ 05:00 Ngo
Hebrew ➙ 05:00 אחה״צ
Manx (Isle of Man) ➙ 05:00 p.m.
Macedonian (Macedonia) ➙ 05:00 попладне
English (Trinidad & Tobago) ➙ 05:00 PM
Taita ➙ 05:00 luma lwa p
Slovenian (Slovenia) ➙ 05:00 pop.
French (Haiti) ➙ 05:00 PM
Telugu (India) ➙ 05:00 PM
Dutch (Sint Maarten) ➙ 05:00 p.m.
Northern Luri ➙ 05:00 PM
Koyraboro Senni ➙ 05:00 Aluula
Chechen ➙ 05:00 PM
French (Congo - Brazzaville) ➙ 05:00 PM
French (Belgium) ➙ 05:00 PM
Ngomba (Cameroon) ➙ 05:00 ŋka mbɔ́t nji
Maltese (Malta) ➙ 05:00 PM
Spanish (Venezuela) ➙ 05:00 p. m.
Malagasy ➙ 05:00 PM
Marathi ➙ 05:00 म.उ.
Meru (Kenya) ➙ 05:00 ŨG
Korean ➙ 05:00 오후
Low German (Netherlands) ➙ 05:00 PM
English (Bermuda) ➙ 05:00 PM
Norwegian Bokmål (Norway) ➙ 05:00 p.m.
Akan ➙ 05:00 EW
Sena ➙ 05:00 PM
Makonde ➙ 05:00 Chilo
Dzongkha ➙ 05:00 ཕྱི་ཆ་
Kabuverdianu (Cape Verde) ➙ 05:00 pm
Metaʼ ➙ 05:00 PM
Vietnamese (Vietnam) ➙ 05:00 CH
English (Vanuatu) ➙ 05:00 PM
English (United States) ➙ 05:00 PM
Tongan (Tonga) ➙ 05:00 efiafi
Morisyen (Mauritius) ➙ 05:00 PM
Sena (Mozambique) ➙ 05:00 PM
French (Burkina Faso) ➙ 05:00 PM
Punjabi (Gurmukhi) ➙ 05:00 ਬਾ.ਦੁ.
Italian (San Marino) ➙ 05:00 PM
French (Mayotte) ➙ 05:00 PM
Gujarati (India) ➙ 05:00 PM
Sichuan Yi (China) ➙ 05:00 ꁯꋒ
Punjabi (Arabic, Pakistan) ➙ 05:00 PM
Asturian ➙ 05:00 de la tarde
French (Réunion) ➙ 05:00 PM
Finnish (Finland) ➙ 05:00 ip.
Cantonese (Simplified) ➙ 05:00 下午
Catalan (France) ➙ 05:00 p. m.
Serbian (Latin, Bosnia & Herzegovina) ➙ 05:00 po podne
Bangla (India) ➙ 05:00 PM
French (Guadeloupe) ➙ 05:00 PM
Punjabi ➙ 05:00 ਬਾ.ਦੁ.
Standard Moroccan Tamazight (Morocco) ➙ 05:00 ⵜⴰⴷⴳⴳⵯⴰⵜ
Ukrainian (Ukraine) ➙ 05:00 пп
French (Djibouti) ➙ 05:00 PM
Rundi ➙ 05:00 Z.MW.
Tajik ➙ 05:00 па. чо.
Rwa ➙ 05:00 kyiukonyi
Hungarian ➙ 05:00 du.
French (Switzerland) ➙ 05:00 PM
English (Norfolk Island) ➙ 05:00 PM
Tasawaq ➙ 05:00 Zaarikay b
Hausa (Ghana) ➙ 05:00 PM
Serbian (Cyrillic, Kosovo) ➙ 05:00 по подне
Bambara ➙ 05:00 PM
Arabic (South Sudan) ➙ 05:00 م
English (Guam) ➙ 05:00 PM
Dutch (Aruba) ➙ 05:00 p.m.
German (Belgium) ➙ 05:00 nachm.
English (Anguilla) ➙ 05:00 PM
English (Cameroon) ➙ 05:00 PM
Soga (Uganda) ➙ 05:00 Eigulo
Czech (Czechia) ➙ 05:00 odp.
Turkish ➙ 05:00 ÖS
Catalan (Spain) ➙ 05:00 p. m.
Chiga ➙ 05:00 PM
Romansh (Switzerland) ➙ 05:00 PM
Nyankole (Uganda) ➙ 05:00 PM
Russian (Moldova) ➙ 05:00 PM
Malay (Malaysia) ➙ 05:00 PTG
Tamil (Sri Lanka) ➙ 05:00 பிற்பகல்
Bafia ➙ 05:00 cɛɛ́nko
English (Tonga) ➙ 05:00 PM
Welsh ➙ 05:00 yh
English (Papua New Guinea) ➙ 05:00 PM
French (Central African Republic) ➙ 05:00 PM
Portuguese (Timor-Leste) ➙ 05:00 da tarde
Albanian ➙ 05:00 e pasdites
French ➙ 05:00 PM
Tajik (Tajikistan) ➙ 05:00 па. чо.
English (Eritrea) ➙ 05:00 PM
Quechua (Peru) ➙ 05:00 p.m.
Serbian (Bosnia & Herzegovina) ➙ 05:00 по подне
Spanish (Paraguay) ➙ 05:00 p. m.
German ➙ 05:00 nachm.
Spanish (Ecuador) ➙ 05:00 p. m.
Konkani (India) ➙ 05:00 म.नं.
Ganda (Uganda) ➙ 05:00 PM
Zulu (South Africa) ➙ 05:00 PM
French (Togo) ➙ 05:00 PM
Serbian (Latin, Kosovo) ➙ 05:00 po podne
English (Philippines) ➙ 05:00 PM
Igbo (Nigeria) ➙ 05:00 P.M.
French (Guinea) ➙ 05:00 PM
Prussian (World) ➙ 05:00 PM
Chiga (Uganda) ➙ 05:00 PM
Chinese (Simplified, Macau SAR China) ➙ 05:00 下午
Colognian (Germany) ➙ 05:00 Uhr nommendaachs
Ganda ➙ 05:00 PM
Russian (Russia) ➙ 05:00 PM
Northern Sami (Finland) ➙ 05:00 eb
Fulah ➙ 05:00 kikiiɗe
English (Dominica) ➙ 05:00 PM
English (Cook Islands) ➙ 05:00 PM
Sindhi ➙ 05:00 منجهند، شام
Arabic (Morocco) ➙ 05:00 م
Irish (Ireland) ➙ 05:00 i.n.
English (Burundi) ➙ 05:00 PM
English (Antigua & Barbuda) ➙ 05:00 PM
French (Chad) ➙ 05:00 PM
English (Samoa) ➙ 05:00 PM
French (Luxembourg) ➙ 05:00 PM
Embu (Kenya) ➙ 05:00 UT
Bemba (Zambia) ➙ 05:00 akasuba
Soga ➙ 05:00 Eigulo
Ewondo (Cameroon) ➙ 05:00 ngəgógəle
French (Congo - Kinshasa) ➙ 05:00 PM
Somali ➙ 05:00 gn.
Rundi (Burundi) ➙ 05:00 Z.MW.
English (Namibia) ➙ 05:00 PM
Arabic (Eritrea) ➙ 05:00 م
Kabyle ➙ 05:00 n tmeddit
Malay ➙ 05:00 PTG
Nuer ➙ 05:00 TŊ
Shona (Zimbabwe) ➙ 05:00 PM
Prussian ➙ 05:00 PM
Hebrew (Israel) ➙ 05:00 אחה״צ
Uyghur ➙ 05:00 چۈشتىن كېيىن
Spanish (Ceuta & Melilla) ➙ 05:00 p. m.
Thai (Thailand, TH, Thai Digits) ➙ 05:00 หลังเที่ยง
Hindi ➙ 05:00 अपराह्न
French (Seychelles) ➙ 05:00 PM
Catalan (Italy) ➙ 05:00 p. m.
Langi (Tanzania) ➙ 05:00 MUU
English (Sierra Leone) ➙ 05:00 PM
Teso (Kenya) ➙ 05:00 Ebongi
Norwegian (Norway) ➙ 05:00 p.m.
Catalan (Andorra) ➙ 05:00 p. m.
Chinese (Traditional, Macau SAR China) ➙ 05:00 下午
English (St. Helena) ➙ 05:00 PM
Vai ➙ 05:00 PM
Quechua (Bolivia) ➙ 05:00 p.m.
Hawaiian (United States) ➙ 05:00 PM
Vietnamese ➙ 05:00 CH
French (Canada) ➙ 05:00 p.m.
German (Luxembourg) ➙ 05:00 nachm.
Albanian (Kosovo) ➙ 05:00 e pasdites
Jola-Fonyi ➙ 05:00 PM
English (Cayman Islands) ➙ 05:00 PM
Maltese ➙ 05:00 PM
Italian (Switzerland) ➙ 05:00 PM
German (Germany) ➙ 05:00 nachm.
Sinhala (Sri Lanka) ➙ 05:00 ප.ව.
Luo (Kenya) ➙ 05:00 OT
English (Denmark) ➙ 05:00 PM
Yangben ➙ 05:00 kisɛ́ndɛ
Somali (Djibouti) ➙ 05:00 gn.
Lithuanian (Lithuania) ➙ 05:00 popiet
Italian (Italy) ➙ 05:00 PM
Esperanto ➙ 05:00 ptm
Kamba ➙ 05:00 Ĩyawĩoo
Arabic (Somalia) ➙ 05:00 م
English (Zimbabwe) ➙ 05:00 PM
Romanian ➙ 05:00 p.m.
Esperanto (World) ➙ 05:00 ptm
Ewe ➙ 05:00 ɣetrɔ
English (U.S. Outlying Islands) ➙ 05:00 PM
Norwegian Nynorsk (Norway) ➙ 05:00 ettermiddag
French (Mauritius) ➙ 05:00 PM
Polish ➙ 05:00 PM
Northern Sami (Sweden) ➙ 05:00 eahketbeaivet
English (Tokelau) ➙ 05:00 PM
English (Slovenia) ➙ 05:00 PM
Mundang (Cameroon) ➙ 05:00 lilli
Urdu ➙ 05:00 PM
Uzbek (Arabic) ➙ 05:00 PM
Vai (Vai, Liberia) ➙ 05:00 PM
Samburu (Kenya) ➙ 05:00 Teipa
Northern Sami ➙ 05:00 eahketbeaivet
Portuguese (Guinea-Bissau) ➙ 05:00 da tarde
Lao (Laos) ➙ 05:00 ຫຼັງທ່ຽງ
Cherokee ➙ 05:00 ᏒᎯᏱᎢᏗᏢ
Arabic (Lebanon) ➙ 05:00 م
Afrikaans (South Africa) ➙ 05:00 nm.
Malay (Singapore) ➙ 05:00 PTG
Ewe (Togo) ➙ 05:00 ɣetrɔ
Lingala (Angola) ➙ 05:00 mpókwa
Belarusian (Belarus) ➙ 05:00 PM
Fulah (Guinea) ➙ 05:00 kikiiɗe
Cantonese (Traditional) ➙ 05:00 下午
Indonesian (Indonesia) ➙ 05:00 PM
Spanish (Belize) ➙ 05:00 p.m.
Arabic (United Arab Emirates) ➙ 05:00 م
Croatian (Croatia) ➙ 05:00 PM
Luyia ➙ 05:00 p.m.
Assamese ➙ 05:00 অপৰাহ্ন
Rombo (Tanzania) ➙ 05:00 kingoto
Italian ➙ 05:00 PM
Portuguese (Cape Verde) ➙ 05:00 da tarde
Kashmiri (India) ➙ 05:00 PM
Ukrainian ➙ 05:00 пп
Burmese (Myanmar (Burma)) ➙ 05:00 ညနေ
Urdu (Pakistan) ➙ 05:00 PM
Mongolian (Mongolia) ➙ 05:00 ү.х
Danish (Denmark) ➙ 05:00 PM
English (Micronesia) ➙ 05:00 PM
Spanish (Puerto Rico) ➙ 05:00 p. m.
Walser (Switzerland) ➙ 05:00 PM
Mazanderani ➙ 05:00 PM
English (Belgium) ➙ 05:00 PM
Sichuan Yi ➙ 05:00 ꁯꋒ
Tatar ➙ 05:00 PM
French (Wallis & Futuna) ➙ 05:00 PM
Russian (Belarus) ➙ 05:00 PM
Mazanderani (Iran) ➙ 05:00 PM
Nama ➙ 05:00 ǃuias
Faroese (Denmark) ➙ 05:00 PM
English (Singapore) ➙ 05:00 PM
Ewe (Ghana) ➙ 05:00 ɣetrɔ
Arabic (Bahrain) ➙ 05:00 م
Kalenjin (Kenya) ➙ 05:00 kooskoliny
Central Atlas Tamazight ➙ 05:00 Ḍeffir aza
Friulian ➙ 05:00 p.
Oromo ➙ 05:00 WB
Hindi (India) ➙ 05:00 अपराह्न
English (Switzerland) ➙ 05:00 PM
Asu ➙ 05:00 ichamthi
Yoruba (Benin) ➙ 05:00 Ɔ̀sán
Faroese (Faroe Islands) ➙ 05:00 PM
Asturian (Spain) ➙ 05:00 de la tarde
French (Comoros) ➙ 05:00 PM
Bena (Tanzania) ➙ 05:00 pamunyi
French (Martinique) ➙ 05:00 PM
English (Sudan) ➙ 05:00 PM
Spanish (Argentina) ➙ 05:00 p. m.
English (Malaysia) ➙ 05:00 PM
Japanese (Japan, JP, Japanese Calendar) ➙ 05:00 午後
Spanish (El Salvador) ➙ 05:00 p. m.
Portuguese (Brazil) ➙ 05:00 PM
Malayalam (India) ➙ 05:00 PM
Sangu (Tanzania) ➙ 05:00 Pashamihe
Filipino ➙ 05:00 PM
English (Falkland Islands) ➙ 05:00 PM
Uzbek (Cyrillic) ➙ 05:00 ТК
Icelandic (Iceland) ➙ 05:00 e.h.
Cantonese (Traditional, Hong Kong SAR China) ➙ 05:00 下午
Armenian (Armenia) ➙ 05:00 ԿՀ
English (Gambia) ➙ 05:00 PM
English (Diego Garcia) ➙ 05:00 PM
Faroese ➙ 05:00 PM
Nepali (Nepal) ➙ 05:00 अपराह्न
Croatian ➙ 05:00 PM
Portuguese (São Tomé & Príncipe) ➙ 05:00 da tarde
Akan (Ghana) ➙ 05:00 EW
Lithuanian ➙ 05:00 popiet
Uzbek (Arabic, Afghanistan) ➙ 05:00 PM
Friulian (Italy) ➙ 05:00 p.
Tamil (India) ➙ 05:00 பிற்பகல்
Chakma ➙ 05:00 PM
English (Sweden) ➙ 05:00 PM
French (French Guiana) ➙ 05:00 PM
Lakota ➙ 05:00 PM
Chinese (Simplified, China) ➙ 05:00 下午
Icelandic ➙ 05:00 e.h.
Spanish (Latin America) ➙ 05:00 p.m.
Sinhala ➙ 05:00 ප.ව.
Portuguese (Angola) ➙ 05:00 da tarde
English (World) ➙ 05:00 PM
English ➙ 05:00 PM
Gusii (Kenya) ➙ 05:00 Mog
Swiss German (Liechtenstein) ➙ 05:00 am Namittag
Chakma (Bangladesh) ➙ 05:00 PM
Spanish (Canary Islands) ➙ 05:00 p. m.
Catalan ➙ 05:00 p. m.
Russian (Kyrgyzstan) ➙ 05:00 PM
French (Mauritania) ➙ 05:00 PM
Arabic (Tunisia) ➙ 05:00 م
Kashmiri ➙ 05:00 PM
Chinese (Traditional, Taiwan) ➙ 05:00 下午
Bambara (Mali) ➙ 05:00 PM
Cornish (United Kingdom) ➙ 05:00 p.m.
Uyghur (China) ➙ 05:00 چۈشتىن كېيىن
Assamese (India) ➙ 05:00 অপৰাহ্ন
Spanish (Brazil) ➙ 05:00 p.m.
Chinese (Hong Kong SAR China) ➙ 05:00 下午
Koyra Chiini (Mali) ➙ 05:00 Aluula
Swahili (Kenya) ➙ 05:00 PM
English (Solomon Islands) ➙ 05:00 PM
Thai (Thailand) ➙ 05:00 หลังเที่ยง
Kinyarwanda (Rwanda) ➙ 05:00 PM
Cherokee (United States) ➙ 05:00 ᏒᎯᏱᎢᏗᏢ
Tachelhit (Tifinagh, Morocco) ➙ 05:00 ⵜⴰⴷⴳⴳⵯⴰⵜ
Arabic (Iraq) ➙ 05:00 م
Nyankole ➙ 05:00 PM
Cantonese ➙ 05:00 下午
Machame ➙ 05:00 kyiukonyi
English (Malawi) ➙ 05:00 PM
Nama (Namibia) ➙ 05:00 ǃuias
Macedonian ➙ 05:00 попладне
English (British Indian Ocean Territory) ➙ 05:00 PM
Arabic (Qatar) ➙ 05:00 م
English (Germany) ➙ 05:00 PM
Punjabi (Arabic) ➙ 05:00 PM
English (Cocos (Keeling) Islands) ➙ 05:00 PM
Bosnian ➙ 05:00 popodne
Romanian (Moldova) ➙ 05:00 p.m.
English (Finland) ➙ 05:00 PM
Portuguese (Portugal) ➙ 05:00 da tarde
Western Frisian ➙ 05:00 PM
Azerbaijani (Cyrillic, Azerbaijan) ➙ 05:00 ПМ
Thai ➙ 05:00 หลังเที่ยง
Taita (Kenya) ➙ 05:00 luma lwa p
Central Kurdish (Iraq) ➙ 05:00 د.ن
Tachelhit (Latin, Morocco) ➙ 05:00 tadggʷat
Spanish (Cuba) ➙ 05:00 p.m.
Arabic ➙ 05:00 م
English (Seychelles) ➙ 05:00 PM
English (U.S. Virgin Islands) ➙ 05:00 PM
Hawaiian ➙ 05:00 PM
Basque (Spain) ➙ 05:00 PM
English (Uganda) ➙ 05:00 PM
English (New Zealand) ➙ 05:00 PM
Zarma ➙ 05:00 Zaarikay b
Spanish (Uruguay) ➙ 05:00 p. m.
Basaa ➙ 05:00 I ɓugajɔp
Masai (Kenya) ➙ 05:00 Ɛndámâ
Russian (Ukraine) ➙ 05:00 PM
Sango (Central African Republic) ➙ 05:00 LK
Greek (Greece) ➙ 05:00 μ.μ.
Yangben (Cameroon) ➙ 05:00 kisɛ́ndɛ
Uzbek (Latin) ➙ 05:00 TK
Sango ➙ 05:00 LK
Danish (Greenland) ➙ 05:00 PM
English (Fiji) ➙ 05:00 PM
German (Liechtenstein) ➙ 05:00 nachm.
English (Barbados) ➙ 05:00 PM
Khmer (Cambodia) ➙ 05:00 PM
Inari Sami (Finland) ➙ 05:00 ep.
Croatian (Bosnia & Herzegovina) ➙ 05:00 PM
German (Austria) ➙ 05:00 nachm.
Central Kurdish (Iran) ➙ 05:00 د.ن
Dutch ➙ 05:00 p.m.
Luba-Katanga (Congo - Kinshasa) ➙ 05:00 Dilolo
Catalan (Spain, Valencian) ➙ 05:00 p. m.
Arabic (World) ➙ 05:00 م
Somali (Somalia) ➙ 05:00 gn.
Latvian (Latvia) ➙ 05:00 pēcpusdienā
Central Kurdish ➙ 05:00 د.ن
Spanish (Costa Rica) ➙ 05:00 p. m.
French (Gabon) ➙ 05:00 PM
Arabic (Kuwait) ➙ 05:00 م
Serbian ➙ 05:00 по подне
Arabic (Libya) ➙ 05:00 م
Serbian (Cyrillic, Serbia) ➙ 05:00 по подне
Bemba ➙ 05:00 akasuba
English (Mauritius) ➙ 05:00 PM
Danish ➙ 05:00 PM
Walser ➙ 05:00 PM
Galician (Spain) ➙ 05:00 p.m.
English (Isle of Man) ➙ 05:00 PM
Azerbaijani (Latin, Azerbaijan) ➙ 05:00 PM
English (Lesotho) ➙ 05:00 PM
Igbo ➙ 05:00 P.M.
English (Hong Kong SAR China) ➙ 05:00 PM
English (Gibraltar) ➙ 05:00 PM
Chechen (Russia) ➙ 05:00 PM
English (Canada) ➙ 05:00 p.m.
Scottish Gaelic ➙ 05:00 f
Georgian (Georgia) ➙ 05:00 PM
French (Syria) ➙ 05:00 PM
Swahili (Tanzania) ➙ 05:00 PM
French (Rwanda) ➙ 05:00 PM
Somali (Ethiopia) ➙ 05:00 gn.
Dutch (Belgium) ➙ 05:00 p.m.
Arabic (Djibouti) ➙ 05:00 م
Malagasy (Madagascar) ➙ 05:00 PM
Welsh (United Kingdom) ➙ 05:00 yh
English (British Virgin Islands) ➙ 05:00 PM
Church Slavic ➙ 05:00 PM
Ossetic (Russia) ➙ 05:00 ӕмбисбоны фӕстӕ
Serbian (Latin, Serbia) ➙ 05:00 po podne
English (Turks & Caicos Islands) ➙ 05:00 PM
Kyrgyz (Kyrgyzstan) ➙ 05:00 түштөн кийинки
Swedish (Åland Islands) ➙ 05:00 em
Afrikaans (Namibia) ➙ 05:00 nm.
Vunjo ➙ 05:00 kyiukonyi
English (India) ➙ 05:00 PM
Luba-Katanga ➙ 05:00 Dilolo
Kikuyu ➙ 05:00 Hwaĩ-inĩ
Yoruba ➙ 05:00 Ọ̀sán
Spanish (Nicaragua) ➙ 05:00 p. m.
Norwegian Bokmål ➙ 05:00 p.m.
Fulah (Mauritania) ➙ 05:00 kikiiɗe
Sindhi (Pakistan) ➙ 05:00 منجهند، شام
Masai (Tanzania) ➙ 05:00 Ɛndámâ
Tigrinya ➙ 05:00 ድሕር ሰዓት
Konkani ➙ 05:00 म.नं.
Ewondo ➙ 05:00 ngəgógəle
Malay (Brunei) ➙ 05:00 PTG
Chakma (India) ➙ 05:00 PM
Breton (France) ➙ 05:00 G.M.
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Comment: Your answer doesn't seem to answer the specific question asked (that is: _"Notice the "chiều" instead of PM. This is required."_).

Answer (score 2):

You can simply do it by passing your timestamp values in Millis to function as below.

Here in this function `Locale` is passed as default, so whatever your phone language is, result will be accordingly returned.

```
  public static String millisToFormat(long millis) {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.getDefault());
        cal.setTimeZone(tz);
        cal.setTimeInMillis(millis);
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm aa", Locale.getDefault());
        sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
        return sdf.format(cal.getTime());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SimpleDateFormat` for this job. You specify a notation (eg. `dd/MM/yyyy` or `dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss` , and your timestamp will be shown in that format (eg. 25/01/2019 or 25/01/2019 23:16:54)

Example:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
String dateString = formatter.format(new Date(Long.parseLong(timestamp)));
txtDate.setText(dateString);
```

Comment: *You specify a notation,*  - please show an example of what you mean.

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Comment: Please have a look at the other answers. It should suffice to your use case