# Getting AM/PM information from LocalDateTime instance

Tags: java, date, java-8

I am taking time input from user as a `String` in `Java` and then converting it to `LocalDateTime` object and saving it in a text file.

**Problem**

`hh:mm a` is the format in which i am taking input form user. If i enter `12:30 PM`, it is saved in text file with current date as `2019-03-20T12:30` without indication of `AM` or `PM`.

Consequently, when i read it from text file, i get the date-time information without `AM` or `PM`.

**Question**

Why is `AM` or `PM` not saved in the text file and how can i get it from `LocalDateTime` instance?

**Code**

Following method takes input from user, converts the user input in to `LocalDateTime` instance and returns it which is then saved to text file as a `String`

```
private static LocalDateTime getTimeInput(String question) {        
    System.out.print(question);
    String userInput = scanner.nextLine();

    userInput = AppointmentManager.validateTimeString(userInput, question);

    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd h:m a");
    String todaysDateString = LocalDate.now().toString();
    userInput = todaysDateString + " " + userInput;

    return LocalDateTime.parse(userInput, formatter);       
}
```

`validateTimeString` function is used to verify that user input is in correct format

Following method saves the data to text file

```
private static final File file = new File("appointments_data.txt");

public static void saveAppointmentInfo(Appointment appointment, boolean appendToFile) {     
    try (FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file, appendToFile);
        BufferedWriter bfw = new BufferedWriter(fw)) {

        String str = AppointmentDataManager.getAppointmentInfoAsString(appointment);

        bfw.write(str);
        bfw.newLine();

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

`getAppointmentInfoAsString` method

```
private static String getAppointmentInfoAsString(Appointment appointment) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    sb.append(appointment.getPatientId())
       .append(";")
       .append(appointment.getStartTime())
       .append(";")
       .append(appointment.getEndTime())
       .append(";")
       .append(appointment.getDoctor().getName());

    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: Please show the code you're using to save the `LocalDateTime` into the text file and how you're then parsing it later. Basically you're saving ISO-8601 format, with a 24-hour time. 12:30AM would be 00:30. That's a *good* thing if it's intended to be machine-readable. If you wanted formatting for humans, that's a whole big different mess.

Comment: You can have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38250379/java8-datetimeformatter-am-pm), it may help... Otherwise show your code here, please.

Comment: @Nick you still haven't showed how you are saving `LocalDateTime` to file.

Comment: You've shown the code you've used to parse the input from the user, but you haven't shown the code used to either save *or* load the file.

Comment: @JonSkeet i have included code to save data in text file, data is saved as a `String` and then loaded as `String` which is then converted to `LocalDateTime` using `parse` method of `LocalDateTIme` class

Comment: "which is then converted to LocalDateTime using parse method of LocalDateTIme class" - but again, without any information about *how* you're calling that method. I'm afraid I'm going to have to bow out at this point, as I don't have enough time to get one piece of information at a time. A [mcve] that shows saving and loading the file would greatly help others who are trying to help you.

Comment: @JonSkeet _without any information about how you're calling that method_ when date is read from file as a `String`, i call `LocalDateTime time = LocalDateTime.parse(datetime);` where `datetime` is a `String` variable which contains data read from text file.

Comment: Please include that in the question - again, ideally as an [mcve]. But in that case I'd expect it to work perfectly well with the format you've got by default from the implicit `toString` call. Both use ISO-8601.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are using `StringBuilder` you are calling `LocalDateTime.toString()` when the `String` segment is appended. As per `LocalDateTime.toString()` method javadoc:

> The output will be one of the following ISO-8601 formats:
>
> - uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm
> - uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss
> - uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS
> - uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS
> - uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSSSS

You need to save `LocalDateTime` with custom format to get AM/PM:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd h:m a");

sb.append(appointment.getPatientId())
   .append(";")
   .append(appointment.getStartTime().format(formatter))
   .append(";")
   .append(appointment.getEndTime().format(formatter))
   .append(";")
   .append(appointment.getDoctor().getName());
```

Comment: The code that the OP has shown for parsing is used to parse the user input - not necessarily the text file. We haven't got clarity on that yet.

Comment: @JonSkeet I know, but the format reduced to just minutes is a bit of a give away.

Comment: It's not clear that the OP should really be changing how they save their file at all. If the intention is for it to be machine-readable, then ISO-8601 format is great. We really need more information in order to help.

Comment: @Nick: Note that if the intention is for this to be a machine-readable file, the format you had before is generally preferable - and should already have been working.

Comment: Don’t store the user’s preferred format in the text file. The ISO 8601 format already stored there is better suited for that. Only format the `LocalDateTime` when displaying it to the uuser.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at simple example of how to do it. Apply it accordignaly.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("KK:mm:ss a", Locale.ENGLISH);
        String now = LocalDateTime.now().format(formatter);
        System.out.println(now);
}
```

This is only for Java 1.8 and later.

Sign    Meaning                 Type                Example

a       Am/pm marker            Text                PM

K       Hour in am/pm (0-11)    Number              0