# DateTimeFormatterBuilder with am/pm

Tags: java, date, datetime-parsing, datetimeformatter

I'm trying to build a date time format that accepts AM and PM stamps. For example, whenever the LocalTime.parse("12:00 am") in java is called, with the default format, an exception is thrown. So I'm adding my own format like this

```
String time = "2:00 am"

DateTimeFormatter format = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                        .appendValue(HOUR_OF_DAY, 2)
                        .appendLiteral(':')
                        .appendValue(MINUTE_OF_HOUR, 2)
                        .optionalStart()
                        .appendLiteral(':')
                        .appendValue(SECOND_OF_MINUTE, 2)
                        .optionalStart()
                        .appendValue(AMPM_OF_DAY)
                        .toFormatter();

LocalTime.parse(time, format);
```

How ever it seems that it doesn't work. I get:

> Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException:
> Text '2:00 am' could not be parsed at index 0

How can I build a correct DateTimeFormatterBuilder that parses the following strings: "2:00 am", "12:15 pm"? And yes I'm aware that you can append formats, but in this case it's needed to use appending values.

Comment: The only reference of `AMPM_OF_DAY` I see in this doc says you use `appendText` instead. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html
appendText(ChronoField.AMPM_OF_DAY, TextStyle.SHORT)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java8 DateTimeFormatter am/pm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38250379/java8-datetimeformatter-am-pm)

Comment: The 2nd `optionalStart()` should most likely be an `optionalEnd()`. Then, we are missing a blank between the minutes (seconds) and the `am/pm`-part. Then, `AMPM_OF_DAY` must be appended as `text`. Finally, we cannot take the hour of day as-is, but must take the `CLOCK_HOUR_OF_AMPM`.

Comment: @BasilBourque I disagree with the duplicate assesment. The problem in the question has nothing to do with the suggested answer. The problem is that the OP is using `HOUR_OF_DAY` instead of `CLOCK_HOUR_OF_AMPM`. If he changes that, uses `.appendLiteral(" ").appendText(AMPM_OF_DAY)` the problem is solved using the builder. The suggested answer is not about the builder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Since hour within AM or PM can be 1 digit, specify so. Use the overloaded `appendValue` method that accepts a minimum and a maximum field width.
2. As Edwin Daloezo already said, you probably want `ChronoField.CLOCK_HOUR_OF_AMPM`.
3. You need am or pm unconditionally, so it should be outside of `optionalStart()` … `optionalEnd()` as Turing85 said in a comment.
4. Consider whether you need to accept `am` or `AM` or both. In that last case you need to specify *case insensitive parsing*.
5. Always specify a locale (a language) for your formatters. While AM and PM are hardly used in other langauges than English, they do have different values (texts) in other languages.

So my go is:

```
    String time = "2:00 am";

    DateTimeFormatter format = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .appendValue(ChronoField.CLOCK_HOUR_OF_AMPM, 1, 2, SignStyle.NEVER)
            .appendLiteral(':')
            .appendValue(ChronoField.MINUTE_OF_HOUR, 2)
            .optionalStart()
            .appendLiteral(':')
            .appendValue(ChronoField.SECOND_OF_MINUTE, 2)
            .optionalEnd()
            .appendLiteral(' ')
            .appendText(ChronoField.AMPM_OF_DAY)
            .toFormatter(Locale.forLanguageTag("en-AU"));

    System.out.println(LocalTime.parse(time, format));
```

Output is:

> 02:00

In Australian English am and pm are in lower case (according to my Java 11), so I specified this locale. Which you should only do if your input comes from Australia, or it will just confuse (there are a few more locales where am and pm are in lower case). To accept lower case am and pm from another English-speaking locale, use `parseCaseInsensitive()`. For example:

```
    DateTimeFormatter format = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .appendValue(ChronoField.CLOCK_HOUR_OF_AMPM, 1, 2, SignStyle.NEVER)
            .appendLiteral(':')
            .appendValue(ChronoField.MINUTE_OF_HOUR, 2)
            .optionalStart()
            .appendLiteral(':')
            .appendValue(ChronoField.SECOND_OF_MINUTE, 2)
            .optionalEnd()
            .appendLiteral(' ')
            .parseCaseInsensitive() // Accept AM or am
            .appendText(ChronoField.AMPM_OF_DAY)
            .toFormatter(Locale.ENGLISH);
```

### If you want a format pattern string

This is no recommendation per se. If you *do not* need case insensitive parsing, it is possible to build your formatter from a format pattern string rather than a builder. On one hand it may be even more error-prone, on the other it’s much shorter.

```
    DateTimeFormatter format = DateTimeFormatter
            .ofPattern("h:mm[.ss] a", Locale.forLanguageTag("en-AU"));
```

Output is the same as before. The square brackets in the format pattern string specify that the seconds are optional.

If you *do need* case insensitive parsing, you do need the builder for specifying it.

You may also mix the approaches since a builder too accepts a format pattern string:

```
    DateTimeFormatter format = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .parseCaseInsensitive() // Accept AM or am
            .appendPattern("h:mm[.ss] a")
            .toFormatter(Locale.ENGLISH);
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to change `HOUR_OF_DAY` which goes from (0-23) to `CLOCK_HOUR_OF_AMPM` which goes from (1-12). I also added a space literal before AM/PM and used `appendText` instead of `appendValue` for the AM/PM field.

The following works just fine.

```java
var formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                .appendValue(CLOCK_HOUR_OF_AMPM, 2)
                .appendLiteral(':')
                .appendValue(MINUTE_OF_HOUR, 2)
                .optionalStart()
                .appendLiteral(":")
                .appendValue(SECOND_OF_MINUTE, 2)
                .optionalStart()
                .appendLiteral(" ")
                .appendText(AMPM_OF_DAY)
                .toFormatter();

        //formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder().appendPattern("hh:mm:ss a").toFormatter();
var time = LocalTime.parse("07:20:54 AM", formatted);
System.out.println(time);  // 19:20:54
```